# Trying to verify file signature in GPG4win: Not enough information to check signature validity

Tags: thunderbird, pgp, enigmail, openpgp, gpg4win

I've downloaded enigmail for Thunderbird and I'm trying to verify the PGP signature with GPG4win.

I imported the public certificate, certified it with my own, downloaded the Open PGP signature, and when verifying it in GPG4win I get the following message, which seems ambiguous:

```
enigmail-1.7-tb+sm.xpi.asc: Not enough information to check signature validity.

Signed on 2014-07-09 13:32 with unknown certificate 0XC936E5C0E21E2C3E
The signature is invalid: No public certificate to verify the signature

Signed on 2014-07-09 13:32 by ....@enigmail.net (Key ID: 0x9369cdf3)
The signature is valid and the certificate's validity is fully trusted.
```

What does this message mean? Does it mean that the file was signed with 2 different signatures and that one validated and the other didn't? If that's the case, can I consider it validated since one signature is valid?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the subkey with ID [0xC936E5C0E21E2C3E](http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?search=0xC936E5C0E21E2C3E&op=index), but it is included in primary key `E443D6D8` and can be downloaded from a key server of your choice:

```
gpg --recv-keys E443D6D8
```

OpenPGP-signed messages do not carry the keys with them, but reference them with their ID.